# Should I check for permission in controller or in service file?

Tags: laravel-10

I have "spaite" package for authorization like for blog read, write, show. Now I have all the authorization check in my controller.

Now I want to implement service pattern. So what should I move to service file? only the business logic or I should move the authorization check also?

Comment: personally, I would still add the construct in controller since they are the first part accessed when doing requests. However, for custom business logic (multiple roles can access the route but single role to execute the business logic) create a separate service class for this and then add the construct...